# Deduce that $\mathbb Q^n$ is countable for any integer $n \in \mathbb N$

Tags: rational-numbers, integers

How do I start this? Do I follow the same proof on why rational numbers are countable?

Comment: By $\mathbb{Q}^n$, do you mean an $n$-tuple of rationals?

Comment: Start by making the body of the Question as self-contained as possible, so that the title does not bear the entire burden of problem statement.  Consider using the "proof on why rational numbers are countable" as a basis step for proof of the wider proposition by induction.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. First of all you may replace $\mathbb Q^n$ with $\mathbb N^n$ and then use induction: $\mathbb N^{n+1}\cong \mathbb N\times \mathbb N^n\cong \mathbb N\times \mathbb N\cong \mathbb N$